# OpenLayers 4 add/remove features/interactions

Tags: openlayers

How can I easily add/remove interaction in OpenLayers 4?

I need to add:

- get layer Info as default (WMS feature on OL2)
- Measure tool. (Already implemented [OpenLayers4 stop interaction](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261106/openlayers4-stop-interaction) but I need an easy way to activate/deactivate the feature)
- Plot a map marker.
- Draw a circle.
- Draw a polygon.

Here a demo with OL2 of what I need to do.

http://www.traffwebdemo.co.uk/rtcplus/

What I need to know if exist some kind of add feature based on which button I click and when I finish with this action (just one interaction) return automatically to the default interaction.

Example:

- the default is getInfo.
- click on draw a circle button
- the feature is activate
- I draw the circle
- automatically the draw feature is removed and getInfo is turn on